# PHP array, assigning two values in array with the first data be exact

Tags: php, arrays

I've some problem to join an array in PHP array, I want the first data to be exact from variable but the second would be dynamic data, here's the example

I have some string like

```
my_str = "TEST"
```

then I would join so the result would be like:

```
my_arr = array(
    array("TEST",22,18),
    array("TEST",15,13),
    array("TEST",5,2),
    array("TEST",17,15)
);
```

how to join the string with the arr so the first index would be always the exact value?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays' depth is always the same, this script below will solve the problem for you. It loops through each element of `$my_arr`, typecasts your `$my_str` to an array  and merges it to the beginning of each element.

```
$my_str = "TEST";

$my_arr = array(
    array(22,18),
    array(15,13),
    array(5,2),
    array(17,15)
);

foreach( $my_arr as &$value ) {
  $value = array_merge( (array) $my_str, $value );
}

print_r( $my_arr );
```